# Pentaho kettle dataflow

Tags: kettle

Soure:  Machine1
Destination: Machine2
Pentaho kettle running on Machine3
A transformation developed and executed on Machine3 that hits database on Machine1 selects data and inserts into a table into another database on Machine2. 
Does that data flow through Machine3 or a direct channel is established between Machine1 and Machine2?

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho will not bridge connections between Machine 1 and Machine 2... **The data will flow through Machine 3 ONLY**. Data from Machine 1 will be processed on Machine 3, and from Machine 3 will be uploaded to Machine 2, no bridges from 1 to 2 directly.